# Building an Offline web app for Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, offline, offline-caching, offlineapps, offline-browsing

I have developed a webapp, which should be available to users even when they are offline. 
I have referred and used "Taking Your Web Apps Offline: A Tale of Web Storage, Application Cache and WebSQL" method for developing this webapp.

For your reference: I have posted a link t o a blog which I referred to develop the webapp.

The offline webapp is working fine but some times When I am trying to access the offline page. 
I get the following error on Chrome browser:

error 106(net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED): the internet connection has been lost

I shouldn't be getting this error as I have already cached the files and while accessing the page I suddenly get this error.

I do not have any idea how to track this error. Please help